# LibGdx - TiledMap - World to screen coordinates (move camera)

Tags: camera, libgdx, coordinates

Initialization of the camera:

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
camera.update();
```

I want to move the camera to the world coordinates (position):

```
private void moveCameraTo(Vector3 position)
{
    OrthographicCamera camera = cameraController.getOrthographicCamera();

    Vector3 newPosition = camera.project(position);
    camera.position.set(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, 0f);
    camera.update();
}
```

But it seems that

```
camera.project(Vector3);
```

always return random coordinates (if I call the method multiple times, the camera will move from point A to point B and point B to point A).

For example, with World coordinates: (x:648.0, y:877.333)

1st call: (x:600, y:360)

2nd call: (x:648, y:877.3)    <-- world coordinates

3rd call: (x:600, y:360)

4th call: (x:648, 877.3)    <-- world coordinates

...

If I manualy move the camera inbetween the different call, the coordinates will change.

I had a similar issue when trying to move a texture to world coordinates. I fixed it by replacing

```
camera.project(pos);
spriteBatch.draw(texture, pos.x, pos.y);
```

by

```
spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
spriteBatch.draw(texture, pos.x, pos.y);
```

Note that:

```
camera.unproject(Vector3);
```

works fine in order to get the world coordinates from the screen coordinates.

Comment: This is because the project method modifies the vector object that you pass in. It is putting the solution into the original vector.

Comment: Yes but :  newPosition == position after calling camera.project(position), I used a variable in order to make it clearer.

Comment: I was explaining why calling it multiple times keeps giving you different results. But if you want to move a camera to a new world position, you should simply change its `position` to the new world position. Projecting is for converting world coordinates to screen coordinates and makes no sense at all for what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, it works fine. For some reason I tought I had to use screen coordinates to move the camera..Thanks ! (should I post the answer to mark it as solved ? I can't use your comment to do so)